# All Objects within a fragment returning null

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

My fragment is not initialising objects correctly. I'm struggling to see why.

Many StackOverflow questions have all suggested adding the following line in the fragment's OnCreateView() should initialise objects correctly.

`mList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.locationList);`

It doesn't seem to be working, as I can see in debug that my Switch and ListView are returning as null. Within my fragment's xml, I have a Switch and ListView id's of lostToggle and locationList appropriately, so they should point to these objects. I'm struggling to see why this is happening. Any help is appreciated.

### page2_fragment.java

```
public class page2_fragment extends Fragment {

    private Switch mToggle;
    private ListView mList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mLocationArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

    public page2_fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2_fragment, container, false);
        mToggle = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.lostToggle);
        mList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.locationList);
        mLocationArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
                items);

        setupLostToggle();
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }

    public ArrayAdapter getArrAdapter() { return mLocationArrayAdapter; }
    public ListView getList() { return mList; }
    public ArrayList<String> getArrayList() { return items; }
    public Switch getToggle() { return mToggle; }

    private void setupLostToggle() {
        //Add "Lost" toggle functionality
        mToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    // The toggle is enabled
                    Log.d("Toggle: ","Enabled");
                } else {
                    // The toggle is disabled
                    Log.d("Toggle: ","Disabled");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### page2_fragment.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.robertdavis.aloost.page2_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/t1_colorPrimaryDark"
        android:baselineAligned="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="@string/keyword_location"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/main_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|end"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="9dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:text="I'm looking for"/>

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerCategory"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.75"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|end"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:text="within"/>

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerRadius"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:text="kilometres." />
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|end"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_getPlacesData"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:onClick="getPlacesData"
                    android:text="Go"
                    android:textAllCaps="true" />

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/lostToggle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                    android:text="Lost? "
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/results_list_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/locationList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit: Logcat data (as requested)**

```
12-10 06:57:20.088 18139-18139/com.example.robertdavis.aloost E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.robertdavis.aloost, PID: 18139
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.robertdavis.aloost.AsyncTaskParseJson.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskParseJson.java:95)
    at com.example.robertdavis.aloost.AsyncTaskParseJson.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskParseJson.java:16)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Are they showing null inside of an android studio error or a crash/stacktrace?

Comment: Both. When debugging I can see that mList and mToggle are null, and when trying to set an adapter onto the list, I get a "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference" error

Comment: is this the complete version of your xml?

Comment: For my fragment, yes

Comment: Do you have a mirror layout file? Say layout-sw600dp/page2_fragment.xml

Comment: I'm new to android development but I'm guessing that's a layout file for a different screen size? Similar to a media query in CSS? In that case, no. page2_fragment.xml is my only layout file for page2_fragment.java

Comment: post logcat also, please

Comment: Added as an edit in the original post

Comment: Why do you think the Fragment is the problem? `at com.example.robertdavis.aloost.AsyncTaskParseJson.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskParseJson.java:95)`... The error is in the AsyncTask.

Comment: ASyncTask only tries to add an ArrayAdapter to a ListView. When the ListView is initialised in the fragment it is null. Here is all that ASyncTask does: `pge2Fragment.getList().setAdapter(pge2Fragment.getArrAdapter());`

Comment: Read about making a [mcve]. You need to actually read the stacktrace, understand what it is trying to tell you. Look at the line number of that class. Line 95 of the AsyncTask. I have no reason to believe the views in your Fragment are null - You have the correct XML. The AsyncTask is the problem, so debug that code, or edit your question again

Comment: If you are dealing with JSON anyway, I would suggest replacing all AsyncTasks with Retrofit. The code is easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

try initialising object in `onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)`
 method

Comment: This didn't seem to work. I'm still getting a NullPointerException on my objects using this method.